# Which releases are supported with semantic versioning of modules?

Tags: updating

I have a site running Drupal 8.9.13.  I have enabled email notification for "only security updates" and it generally works well - I get a mail for "urgent things" otherwise I wait and apply ordinary updates once a month.

Today I received a warning about an unsupported release.  When I check, all I find is an available update.  For [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login), I am running 2.0.0 and 2.1.0 is available.  According to the documentation about [semantic versioning for Drupal modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/3108648), this is a change to the *minor* version.  I don't see any reason why 2.0.0 is in fact unsupported.

From my perspective, this isn't an "urgent thing" and I don't want to be mailed about it every day.  Under the "old" version numbering scheme, a minor version change such as 8.x-3.5 to 8.x-3.6 **does not** cause the same behaviour.

Is this a bug in the Drupal core update module?  Or have I misunderstood how the new semantic version mechanism works?

Screenshot: [image: 3]

Comment: If the notifications are set for _only security updates_, it should not send notifications for updates that aren't tagged *security*.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno I agree with you - except to add that I found even with *only security updates* it does also send notifications if a module is abandoned or if the current *major* version becomes unsupported.

Comment: Interestingly I didn't get another notification today so maybe it was just a glitch.  However on the updates report page, the 2.0.0 version is marked as "Not supported" which doesn't really seem right.  I will add a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an email because the 2.0.0 version has been marked as unsupported by the project maintainer when, on the *Releases* edit form, the *Supported* checkbox for that version has been deselected.

> [image: screenshot]

On Drupal.org, 2.x, 2.0.x, and 2.1.x are considered like three different branches, and have each the setting to make them supported or recommended.
It's not just a matter of version number, but also what the project maintainers mark as supported. Probably, if you had version 2.1.0 installed, that were marked as unsupported, and version 2.0.0 were marked supported, you would get an email telling you the version you installed got unsupported.

Comment: Thanks that is very clear.  The maintainer has "forced" me to make an immediate upgrade.  I hope that this doesn't become a common pattern as more modules move to semantic versioning - it seems pretty unhelpful for site admins if every few days there is an alert about an unsupported module.

Comment: Project maintainers need to get used to semantic versioning, but also the code used on drupal.org probably needs to be fixed. For example, on the screenshot I took, there are three series (`2.1.*`, `2.0.*`, and `2.*`), but the Git branch seems just one (2.x). I am not sure it's correct to make maintainers mark a 2.0.0 version as unsupported, and mark version 2.1.0 as supported, while the same is not possible for 8.x-1.1 and 8.x-1.0. In that screenshot, marking the `8.x-1.*` serie as unsupported would mean to mark both versions as unsupported, not just one of them.

Comment: Also, it's probable the maintainer deselected _Supported_ for 2.0.* because the user interface was showing both the 2.1.0 and 2.0.0 versions on the project page, which is not something he expected. It could be he just wanted to hide the 2.0.0 version, and that is the only way he found to achieve it. Unfortunately, the consequence was sending emails to users who are using the 2.0.0 version.

Comment: Good points, sounds like there should be an issue on Drupal.org.

Comment: I raised https://www.drupal.org/project/infrastructure/issues/3204263.